# modify string to get variable working

Tags: linux, shell, sed

I have the following list:

```
faultsPackage1
faultsPackage2
faultsPackage3
faultsPackage4
faultsPackage5
faultsPackage6
faultsPackage7
seafloor
topLowerMiocene
topMetamorphicBasement
topMiddleEocene
topMiddleMiocene
topMiddleOligocenetoUpperEocene?
topPlioceneFromODP684
topUpperMioceneFromODP684
```

but I need to shape those rows like this (specifically change only those "faultsPackage"):

```
faultsPackage
faultsPackage
faultsPackage
faultsPackage
faultsPackage
faultsPackage
faultsPackage
seafloor
topLowerMiocene
topMetamorphicBasement
topMiddleEocene
topMiddleMiocene
topMiddleOligocenetoUpperEocene?
topPlioceneFromODP684
topUpperMioceneFromODP684
```

because these names represent variables, and these variables will pop up some further processes. I tried:

```
sed 's/[1-7]//'
```

but it deletes all numbers in the list, so it's not useful. I was thinking that, for instance, in somehow it could only be detected the letter "e" followed by numbers from 1-7 and then delete those numbers, but not sure how to implement that in shell.

Any hint will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Would the line always start with `faultsPackage` and have a number behind, or would it be `faults*****number` etc. Just remove number from all lines with `faultsPackageNUMBER` is simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sed should work:

```
sed -i.bak 's/\(faultsPackage\)[0-9]*/\1/' file
```

This regex finds all lines with `faultsPackage<number>` text and replaces it with just `faultsPackage` using captured group #1

Comment: You're welcome. Yes in that case you don't need inline switch.